# Write value of the variable to the config.ini file using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write the value of a variable to configuration file "configfile" but it's writing the variable name. How to go about writing the value of the variable please?

```
config.add_section('TC_count')
config.set('TC_count', 'tc_count', 'items_count')
with open(file, 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

configfile:

```
[TC_count]
tc_count = items_count
```

Comment: How do you normally use a variable `x`? By writing `x` or by writing `'x'`?

Comment: but it has to be written as a string.
'items_count' or items_count both writes as "items_count" only!
Anyway I found a better approach. Thanks anyway.